# Conversation between 2 inner classes

Tags: c++, generics, casting

I have abstract class called List and inner class called AbstractIterator.

I have an class called ArrayList inheriting from List and inner class called Iterator inheriting from List::AbstractIterator.

I'm trying to convert between the abstract List::AbstractIterator to the implemention ArrayList::Iterator. here is part of the code:

```
        bool operator!=(typename List<T>::AbstractIterator& it) {
            typename ArrayList<T>::Iterator itt = it;
```

This is my error:

```
[Error] conversion from 'List<int>::AbstractIterator' to non-scalar type 'ArrayList<int>::Iterator' requested
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the conversion cannot be done implicitly by the compiler and `List<T>::AbstractIterator` is an abstract class you need to use `dynamic_cast` to convert `it`.

```
bool operator!=(List<T>::AbstractIterator& it)
{
    try
    {
        ArrayList<T>::Iterator itt = dynamic_cast<ArrayList<T>::Iterator&>(it);
        // ... other code
    }
    catch(std::bad_cast& e)
    {
        // ... handle case where it is not an ArrayList<T>::iterator
    }

    // ... other code such as return if necessary
}
```

Note that `dynamic_cast` throws `std::bad_cast` when it is unable to convert to a reference. When converting to a pointer type it returns `nullptr` when the conversion cannot be done.

<sub>You *could* use `static_cast` but there is no guarantee that `it` is of type `ArrayList<T>::Iterator` which would result in undefined behavior if it is not.</sub>